# Read each line in a text file when I press a key? C programming

Tags: c, file, key

I know how to use fgets inside a while loop to read an entire text file, but how can I press a key inside that loop, so it will read another line, one at a time?

I tried with a simple printf("Press any key\n") getchar() but nothing happens, I run the programm and it just doesn't do anything, not even show the first line. I'm assuming this may be a stupid question but I can't find how to do this :(

Here is what I've tried:

```
/*  gcc readline.c -Wall -o read */

#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char url[]="dbus.log";
    FILE *arq;
    char info[1000];

    arq = fopen(url, "r");

    while (fgets(info, sizeof(info), arq) != NULL) {        
        printf("%s", info);
        printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");  
        getchar();   
    }

    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: im sorry, but what you mean? isnt getchar() supposed to work with enter as well?

Comment: it can be any key at all for me

Comment: @user3121023 same results, dont work here

Comment: @ryyker dbus.log is on same directory, for some reason it doesnt read one line per keypress, it just "freezes" the terminal before even reading anything, if i comment ('//') the 'printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");' and 'getchar();' it shows me the entire text on terminal, but when I try to use the getchar I doesn't succeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program isn't showing the prompts because stdio is buffered and you're not flushing.  Use fflush(stdout); to ensure that buffered output is produced.

Like this:

```
fflush(stdout);
getchar();
```

Also note that by default stdin is in "cooked" IO mode.  Pressing enter will produce a character, but other characters will be buffered until enter is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for explaining it to me @Art Yerkes! :D